# Replace HTML using php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to match the section shown below and delete it from an html file, have not been successful using regex and I have little knowledge on how to match this section using a php parser and replace it.

```
<table width='100%' class='print_only_wrapper'>
      <thead class='print_only_header'>
           <tr>
             <td align='right' class='print_only_wrapper'>
              SOME TEXT
             </td>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td>
```

This is what I have tried to search the string and replace it

```
if(preg_match("/<thead/", $html)) { 
$string_2_replace="/(<table width='100%' class='print_only_wrapper'>)\s+(<thead class='print_only_header'><tr><td align='right' class='print_only_wrapper'>).+(</td></tr></thead>)\s+(<tbody><tr><td>)/"; 
$html = str_replace($string_2_replace, "", $html); 
}
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: if(preg_match("/<thead/", $html)) {

        $string_2_replace="/(<table width='100%' class='print_only_wrapper'>)\s+(<thead class='print_only_header'><tr><td align='right' class='print_only_wrapper'>).+(</td></tr></thead>)\s+(<tbody><tr><td>)/";

        $html = str_replace($string_2_replace, "", $html);

        }

Comment: use javascript instead

Comment: I'm trying javascript now

Answer (score 0):

Its simply easy,

`\w` - Matches Alphabets with special chars

`\W` - Non Alphabets without special chars

So you try this

```
<table[^>]*?>[\w\W]*?<\/td>$
```

Try this on  for `$string_2_replace`.

then Reply me...

Comment: for some reason is not working. I removed the "$" since this code is embedded within other tags....though it won't change only the text inside, but I just need to remove this piece with html document

Answer (score 0):

So finally I got it!!

this is the $string_2_replace that worked

```
$string_2_replace = '#<table.*?<thead.*?</thead>#';
```